# Ghostscript PDF > JPG конвертирование + CMYK

Tags: изображения, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

Есть файл **PDF, цветовая модель RGB** (размер для примера стандартной визитной карточки - **90х50мм** или ~ **340х188px**).

Есть задача конвертировать его в JPG. Но при этом важно чтобы изображение на выходе тоже было **90х50мм** или ~ **340х188px**.

Если попытаться загнать файл в любой онлайн конвертер, то все они почему-то меняют размер изображения, хотя PDF чётко 90 на 50.

Локально я пробовал через Ghostscript, пробовал через ImageMagick converter, пробовал через другие утилиты. Никто с задачей не справляется.

Действительно нет рабочего решения или что-то не так делаю?

Вот код gs батника для примера:

```
C:\"Program Files"\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe ^
 -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk ^
 -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK ^
 -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK ^
 -dNOPAUSE ^
 -dBATCH ^
 -dJPEGQ=100 ^
 -r300 ^
 -o %~2 ^
  %~1
```

Этот код отдает JPG размером 1108 на 638. 
Если не добавлять -r300, то отдается файл 266 на 133. 
-r100 дает размер 369 на 213.

Я знаю про -g, что можно прописать -g340x188, но он режет не так как нужно. 
Если прописывать -g340x188 при -r300, то отдает пустую картинку. Может есть какие-то доп. параметры для этого?

**Как добиться конвертирования из PDF в JPG(пусть хотя бы RGB), но при этом чтобы размер JPG был 1 в 1 такой же, как 100%-й размер PDF?** Как я не пытался, такого не смог сделать. И ни один сервис не справился с задачей.

PDF прикладываю (может сервис шаринга тоже меняет размер, я не знаю, это просто пример): https://www.docdroid.net/xtvj4bB/pdf-dlya-testa.pdf

И я пробовал на куче разных PDF. Всегда размер меняется при конвертировании в JPG.

Comment: Вы пробовали производить конвертацию при помощи `pdftoppm`? В пп. 3.2 и 4.1 [**этого**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/66632/23324) ответа я давал разъяснения по использованию данной утилиты. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Проблема 1

> Если попытаться загнать файл в любой онлайн конвертер, то все они почему-то меняют размер изображения, хотя PDF чётко 90 на 50.

Это неверно.

Хотим соотношение `90/50`, что равно **1,8**

Теперь посмотрим разрешение с помощью утилиты `pdfinfo`:

```
pdfinfo pdf-dlya-testa.pdf

# Вывод:
Creator:        Chromium
Producer:       Skia/PDF m71
CreationDate:   Sat Nov 23 18:34:25 2019 MSK
ModDate:        Sat Nov 23 18:34:25 2019 MSK
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      265.92 x 153.12 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      31847 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Соотношение `265.92/153.12` равно **1,736677116**, то есть находится в промежутке `90/51 - 90/52`, но никак не `90/50`.

Вывод: исходный файл не соответствует размерам 90 x 50.

## Проблема 2 и решение

Автор [обновил файл](https://yadi.sk/i/GfEvbuLgT2djVA).

`pdfinfo pdf_1_1.pdf` выводит `255.12 x 141.12 pts`, что должно соответствовать 338 x 187 px.

Решение "в лоб":

```sh
convert -colorspace CMYK pdf_1_1.pdf out.jpg && file out.jpg
```

выдает 255x141, 1 пункт преобразуется в 1 пиксель.

Нужно добавить еще параметров. Рабочая команда такая:

```sh
convert -density 400 -resize 338x187 -colorspace CMYK pdf_1_1.pdf out.jpg && file out.jpg
```

- `-density` [предотвращает "замыливание"](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10928)
- `-resize` - выставляет нужный размер

Полученный размер равен 338x187

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Действительно есть некоторая неточность в размерах. И я отправлял pdf-ку размером 94 на 54 (мой косяк).

Но я всё равно не могу понять одну вещь. 
Вот PDF размера 90 на 50 (примерно). https://yadi.sk/i/GfEvbuLgT2djVA 

pdfinfo показывает 255.12 x 141.12 pts; 255.12 / 142.12 = 1.79510273009. 
Что приблизительно равно 338.836922px на 187.428137px. 
Если запустить gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -o pdf.jpg pdf.pdf
то вернется картинка размером 255х141px, что вообще ни разу даже не близко к тем размерам, что были определены выше. Вот вся суть проблемы.

Comment: Если напечатать эту PDF на бумаге, то это будет типовой размер обычной визитки. И это примерно 340px на 188px или 90 на 50 мм. Но никак не 255х141px. Проблема в ghostscript? imagick я не пробовал, он вернет нормальный размер при конвертации в jpg? ghostscript почему-то считает, что pts - это пиксели, а ведь это не так

Comment: @Floyat, я думаю что гостскрипт перевод в отношении 1pt = 1px. Поэтому `255.12 x 141.12 pts` становятся `255 x 141 px`. imagemagic имеет опцию `-resize`. Без ресайта выходи 255x141, если указать ресайз - то нужный размер `338x187`. Но этот ресайз работает на уровне "зума" уже отрастрированного изображения и поэтому замыливается. Я нашел [описание этого бага](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10928). Сейчас попробую разобраться

Comment: @Floyat, я обновил ответ, секция "Проблема 2 и решение"